# customize the number of digits when shown the alphabet

Tags: java, alphabet

The code for displaying all combinations 5 letters is:

```
for(char alphabet = 'A'; alphabet <= 'Z';alphabet++)
        for(char s = 'A'; s <= 'Z';s++)
            for(char b = 'A' ; b <= 'Z';b++)
                for(char f = 'A'; f <= 'Z'; f++)
                    for (char d = 'A'; d <= 'Z'; d++)
                        System.out.println(alphabet+""+s+""+b+""+f+ ""+d );
```

But my boss wants a version in which you could customize which number of letters is displayed for example if he enters "3" it should display "aaa" and if he enters 5 it should display "aaaaa" and that for all combinations of a to z.

Comment: What is the code you provided supposed to do? What is `s`, `b`, `f` and `d`?

Comment: You either have a very bored boss who pays you for doing non-productive work, or this is homework. Anyway, the whole back story is irrelevant, and will be edited out. What you should put in your question instead is your code, where you got stuck, what your initial idea is, etc.

Comment: Please post compilable sample.

Comment: It is supposed to show me how java works, just started working with it today. The letters are the variables @Manu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recursion!:

```
public static class Main {

    public static void main() {
        printAll("",3);
    }

    static void printAll(String prefix, int n) {
        if( n==0 ) {
            System.out.println(prefix);
        } else {
            for(char c='A'; c<= 'Z'; c++) {
                printAll(prefix+c, n-1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Beware! Only run with **small** values of n!

Comment: Unfortunately it is my first time working with java and i don't know what i have to do with that except for copy and paste and a strange error is coming up with the last "printall"

Comment: yup my bad - it was a typo i've fixed - the 'A' in `printAll` needs to be uppercase. Also `c` should be `char`. Copy and paste it again

Comment: Works fine for me... is there an error? try it with n=1 or n=2 (any larger than 3 produces **a lot** of output, which can cause errors)

Comment: Also just to check (as your new to java) the large block is a function you need to add, to actually run the code use `printAll("",3)` in your main function

Comment: Yeah, it tried it, i won't, if you need more information i am using eclipse right now, don't know if it has something to do with it, i also close the code that i had with an "}" and wrote it below that and i used "/*" "*/" to it so it won't show up, have i done a mistake somewhere?

Comment: Ehh, how do i add it?

Comment: Does the new example help? it should sit in your main class like so and then it will be callable from main

Comment: No problem :) please accept the answer with the tick button